# Applying a custom query for the AJAX "us_ajax_grid" function (from WPBakery)

Tags: wp-query, ajax

I have some custom queries that are working properly with pagination if I use the regular pagination numbers, but I want to use the pagination as "page load on scroll" and then apply my custom query.

I'm using WPBakery plugin and for the output I'm using the Grid List.

Here's an example of what I want to achieve:

```
function my_ajax_load_products_callback() {
    $paged = isset($_POST['paged']) ? intval($_POST['paged']) : 1;
    $posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page', 12);

    (...)
    // All my custom conditions here to then generate the args for the query, this is working as intended
    (...)

    $query = new WP_Query($ajax_args);
    
    $shortcode = '[us_grid post_type="ids" ids="' . implode(',', $query->posts) . '" items_quantity="'.$posts_per_page.'" pagination="infinite" items_layout="74977" columns="4" items_gap="1rem"]';

    // Tried this to execute the shortcode and return its output but it's not working properly as it just outputs, strangely, 6 results
    echo do_shortcode($shortcode);
    
    wp_reset_postdata();
    
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_us_ajax_grid', 'my_ajax_load_products_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_us_ajax_grid', 'my_ajax_load_products_callback');
```

As far as it seems, there's no hooks in WPBakery to achieve this (at least not in their documentation).

And this is where my knowledge starts to fail because now I'm stuck with hours of Googling and no solution found so far.

EDIT1: Ok, since I am using the "Impreza theme" here, I thought in maybe doing some changes on my code and instead, creating a loop on the posts and then for the layout, directly use a "us_grid_layout" post type. Problem is, I am not finding neither in code nor in documentation anything about it. Will continue digging and if something is found, will update here.

EDIT2: I think I'm close to a potential solution! I got the answer from Impreza theme support and they mentioned the "us_grid_listing_query_args" hook that I could use to apply filters directly into the grid, which actually works just fine. Now I'm just having problems comparing an array with a serialized array in the database:

```
    function my_custom_grid_query_args($query_args, $defined_vars) {
    $paged = $defined_vars['paged'];
    $posts_per_page = $defined_vars['posts_per_page'];
    
    if (isset($_GET['on_sale']) && $_GET['on_sale'] == 1) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user_roles = $user->roles;
        
        $filter_args = array(
            'post_type'      => array('product', 'product_variation'),
            'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
            'paged'          => $paged,
            'meta_query'     => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => '_promotion_roles',
                    'value'   => $user_roles,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            ),
            'fields'         => 'ids',
            'no_found_rows'  => true,
        );
        $query = new WP_Query($filter_args);
        
        if (!empty($query->posts)) {
            $query_args['post__in'] = array_map('absint', $query->posts);
        } else {
            $query_args['post__in'] = array(0);
        }
    }
    
    return $query_args;
}
add_filter('us_grid_listing_query_args', 'my_custom_grid_query_args', 10, 2);
```